# Insert two scripts in the same <script> tag without conflicts

Tags: javascript

I have to put these two scripts in a single  tag without them coming into conflict but I can not make it. Please, how can I do it?

Also is it better to insert multiple scripts in the same tag?

Script 1

```
var sec = 04;
var hour = 00;
var time0, time1;

var delay=0;
var duringtime = 1000;
time1 = (hour *10000 + min * 100 + parseInt(sec)).toString();

console.log("time1", time1);

function refresh() {
  ........
  }
}
refresh();
```

Script 2

```
var min = 80;
var max = 85;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

if (localStorage.getItem("stockcount_99")) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("stockcount_99") >= duration) {
        var value = random;
    } else {
        var value = localStorage.getItem("stockcount_99");
    }
} else {
    var value = random;
}
document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = value;
var stockcount_99 = function() {
    if (value <= stopValue) { // end count down. <= or >=
        clearInterval(interval);
        value = stopValue;
    } else {
        value = parseInt(value) - 1; // + 1 or - 1
        localStorage.setItem("stockcount_99", value);
    }
    document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = value;
};
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    stockcount_99();
}, speedcontrol);
```

With the following method can I isolate the two scripts and thus prevent any conflicts?

```
(function() {

...script 1...

})()


(function() {

...script 2...

})()
```

Comment: only one `<script>` tag required. What is the conflict you see?

Comment: I don't see any conflicts because I haven't done any tests. But being two different scripts I prefer to avoid problems.

With the following method, do I avoid any conflicts?

`code`
(function() {

...script 1...

})()

(function() {

...script 2...

})()
`code`

Comment: That approach is correct. Put all your javascript into one <script> tag

Comment: can you add the rest of your first script? Perhaps that is what is causing your issue - then we could help you resolve it?

Comment: There are no problems. I just want to isolate the two scripts to prevent any conflicts.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You can also namespace your functions and properties to avoid conflicts.  Namespacing will also make them available outside the IIFE `(function() {} })()`.  Otherwise you've made your function private (eg you can't call "refresh()" anywhere other than inside the first IIFE) - which may be what you want in this case.

Comment: Please how can I name the functions and properties? Can I see an example? Thank you.